# Facebook API - auth.login not triggering

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

I've been using a code to connect to Facebook with my application and it just suddenly didn't work when I checked it again. To be more specific, I am able to connect to Facebook but the auth.login subscription is not triggering and I need to do some stuff after logging in to Facebook. This is my code:

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({ appId: facebookAppId,
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow server to access session 
        xfbml: true,  // enable XFBML and social plugin
        oauth: true   // enable OAuth 2.0
    });
    $('#sender').val('linked');

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.logout();
        }
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
        if (response.status == 'connected') {

            //Get data Facebook returned and save

            //Hide button

            //Display Success Message
        }
        else {
            //Display Failed Message
        }
    });
};

(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
} (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

I have this button in my HTML page:

```
<fb:login-button scope="publish_stream,offline_access">{0}</fb:login-button>
```

Some additional info:

I noticed that there were additional steps added when connecting to Facebook. Last I checked, I just needed to log in using my credentials but I noticed that the current login procedures had two additional steps. I don't know if these additional steps has anything to do with it but I'm just throwing it out there:

1. A dialog box with some info about the app and with a button that says "Login with Facebook".
2. Another dialog box where the app is asking the user for permission to post.

So, what am i doing wrong?:(

Comment: Where/how does the actual login happen in your code? And for the two points you mentioned at the end, no, that’s just how the current Auth dialog works – nothing special about that.

Comment: In my html page, I have this code for the Facebooc Connect button: <fb:login-button scope="publish_stream,offline_access">{0}</fb:login-button>

Answer (score 0):

two things:

- I'm starting to think that facebook did some change in the 'auth.login' that now slowly doesn't work for more and more people.
  see related Q about it -

[FB.Event.Subscribe not working for some users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314844/fb-event-subscribe-not-working-for-some-users/14359311#14359311)

[Auto login facebook - FB.Event.subscribe auth.login doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339899/auto-login-facebook-fb-event-subscribe-auth-login-doesnt-work)

- since you asked it a long time ago, you maybe need to refresh your SDK files if you're using php sdk since its constantly changing.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue that the 'auth.login' wasn't triggered after I refresh the page, I changed:

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login'...
```

to

```
`FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange'...`
```