# FB.Event.Subscribe not working for some users

Tags: php, facebook-javascript-sdk

> FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
>       window.location.href="register_form.php";
>     });

This event is cached for few user account's only, not for everyone

Has facebook made any changes in this regard..Please help

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed problem with FB.even.subscribe but with the 'auth.login' not the 'edge.create'.
more details: 
[Auto login facebook - FB.Event.subscribe auth.login doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339899/auto-login-facebook-fb-event-subscribe-auth-login-doesnt-work)

**I have to assume that there is a bug in facebook** **or change** that done and made things go wrong, **especially if the code was working before** .
I can advise you to use firebug and debug the code lines when I debugged the code lines I found that the problem was with the 'auth.login' because when I replaced it with 'auth.authResponseChange' the FB.Event.subscribe worked, so what I'm saying that it might be 'edge.create' problem in your case.